# How to implement self attention Generator and Discriminator in Conditional Generative Adversarial Nets

Tags: gan

We have a CGAN built with a generator and a discriminator built using neural networks. How can we change the code to implement the same logic using  self attention generator and discriminators?

[Our code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1f9kbpF6giOpzyuJYDjBO_JShxdnpF1Az?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get some help from here [self-attention using keras](https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-self-attention/blob/master/keras_self_attention/seq_self_attention.py). Though I myself cannot solve your problem. As a beginner I would also like to know the answer.